# "ip rule list" command not working correctly on Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, iptables

When I try to execute `sudo ip rule list` or `sudo ip rule` the output just keeps scrolling with the following output. This is on Ubuntu 15.04

```
0:      from all lookup local
0:      from all lookup local
0:      from all lookup local
0:      from all lookup local
0:      from all lookup local
0:      from all lookup local
```

I also tried `sudo ip rule flush` but it just seems to hang in there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was related to a bug in the kernel `3.19.0-37-generic` I was running. For details see https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux-lts-utopic/+bug/1514785

I upgraded my kernel to `3.19.0-49-generic`. It works fine now.

Answer (score 0):

`0: from all lookup local` is a special local routing table. It cannot be deleted or overridden

If you run `ip rule flush` it will result's configured network will be removed in the location `/run/network/ifstate`

If you have logged in through SSH session it will result to Hung-up while providing `ip rule flush`